# Using a C# format string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, string

I have the following C# string

```
var myString= "Unfortunately there has been an error processing {0}'s order"
```

I want to pass that string into my React app and interpolate it in js but there does not seem to be a clean way of doing it

In my React app I want to do something like this

```
myString.format("John Doe")
```

So that I can get this output: `"Unfortunately there has been an error processing John Does's order"`

Some posts I've seen here suggested to create your own `.format()` method in js but I don't want to be reinventing the wheel if there are other solutions out there.

Comment: A format string and an interpolated string are different animals when in comes to usage.

Comment: I've updated title to "format string" as body of the post does not show *interpolated* string - if that is wrong and you are looking for interpolated strings like `$"Bob had {applleCount + pearCount} fruits"` kind of formatting please [edit] to clarify (also that is covered in suggested duplicate too). Please note that looking for libraries (which may be another interpretation of the question) is off-topic on SO - saying that you don't like existing solutions (without even listing them) is not enough...